# Caching mechanism with any type

Tags: c++, caching, boost

I am trying to devise a caching mechanism for my project. Basically, I need a map from a string to a value, however, I need the value to be open and determined at runtime.

What I need is advice about how to implement this.

My design now is this:

- Use `boost::any` to hold the value
- Use `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any>` as container

I'd like a member to give back the **original type**, as I want the cache to be *as transparent as possible*. Users should just use something like this:

```
double      &p = cache.get("p");
std::string &q = cache.get("q");
hugeclass   &r = cache.get("r");
```

I was thinking of having instead of a `boost::any` value, a private struct like this:

```
struct internal
{
    boost::any value;

    template <typename T>
    T& get() { return boost::any_cast<T&>(value); } // Possible?
}
```

However, I don't really know if something like this is possible, or how to really get this.

So, how can I get a transparent caching class that returns references to the held value?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably safer to cache every type separately. Is there any reason you can't do this?

Comment: Not really, but this means that I need to have a container for each type, and I don't know how to comfortably generalize this. If you have an idea, I'd be more than happy!

Comment: I'd just template cache, not get. The user already has to know the type they are getting because of where they are storing it so it doesn't really change their program other than needing to declare multiple caches.

Comment: What should happen if the type is wrong?

Comment: This is free from constraint, I am free to throw (I think `boost::any_cast` actually throws). If I can have an automatic type storage, all the better for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get away with this:

```
double      &p = cache.get<double>("p");
std::string &q = cache.get<std::string>("q");
hugeclass   &r = cache.get<hugeclass>("r");
```

Otherwise, I don't think what you are asking for is possible.

---

UPDATE: You could try a design like this tho:

```
double p;
cache.get("p", p);
```

with the `get` like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool get(const std::string &key, T &output) const {
    // lookup...
    // return false if lookup failed
    output = boost::any_cast<T&>(...);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Right now I am doing exactly this, but I'd like get() to deduce the type somehow, storing it somewhere.

Comment: Pretty sure it's impossible. You could store the type separately, but you won't be able to make this conversion automatically.

Comment: Do you think this will work with inheritance and shared pointers? Something like inserting `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`, and actually getting back the very same type: I fear slicing. Note that I don't care if the user mistakenly or purposely inserts a shared ptr to derived class and asks from the cache the base class shared ptr, or viceversa. I can say "undefined behavior" in this case.